# Amazon MWS Signature - Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, amazon-mws

I have written an application in Delphi in order to sync between multiple storefronts.
I seem to have run into an issue when it comes to the signature. My scenario is this:

When i run the Orders API for Amazon, it will accept the signature and download all the orders successfully. I have not had any issues when it comes to this one.

Now when I switch over to the Reports API, it will not except the signature. 
Here is the signing function i'm using

```
hmac_SHA256_inits(hmc, FSecretAccessKey);
s := StringToSign;
hmac_SHA256_update(hmc, @(s[1]), Length(s));
hmac_SHA256_final(hmc, hmd);
SetLength(sBin, 32);
for i := 0 to 31
 do sBin[i+1] := AnsiChar(hmd[i]);

Result := Base64Encode(sBin);
Result := StringReplace(Result, '+', '%2B', [rfReplaceAll]);
Result := StringReplace(Result, '=', '%3D', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

I have even run this with the same timestamp as the MWS Scratchpad to compare the signaures, and they come out different. Yet the string to sign is exactly the same, word for word, capitalization as well. I would think it might be the signing routine but then how would the Orders API work without any issue if the routine was wrong? The only major difference I can see in the two is that for the Orders API you have to use

POST
/Orders/2011-01-01
ParamterString

and the report one is

POST
/
ParamterString

Could the solo slash be causing the signing to fail? I've tried everything I can think of to fix this and I'm actually considering abandoning the project at this point in favor of a different language.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's the origin of the SHA256 functions you're using? Did you write them, 3rd party library or...?

Comment: Have you solved this? I too am stuck trying to generate a signature for my MWS requests in Delphi.  If you succeeded, would you mind pointing to the right direction as to what SHA/HMAC libraries to use?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely in your `StringToSign` function. It should look somewhat like this:

```
StringToSign := 'POST'+ chr(13)+ 
                 AmazonMWShost + chr(13) + 
                 '/'+ APIurl + chr(13) + 
                 URLencodedParameters;
```

Where AmazonMWShost is `mws.amazonservices.com` for US merchants. APIurl is an empty string for the Report API and `Orders/2011-01-01` for the Order API.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but this may help others... the end-of-line character Amazon uses is Chr(10), not Chr(13) as mentioned above.  Also, if you use Indy to POST the data, be sure to add :443 at the end of the endpoint (AmazonMWShost+':443') in order to calculate the signature correctly, since it will add that to the Host header line item and Amazon will use that value to calculate the signature on their end.